# Algebraic Method

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

Is there a way to solve the following equation algebraically?

$(x+3/5)^{5x-3}=16$

So far, I have figured out a solution to be 7/5. This was solved by comparing the exponential form of 16 but I am not convinced this is the right approach. There is also another solution (negative).

[image]

Comment: So What you are saying is that you have solved it for 

$2^4 = (x+3/5)^{5x-3} $?

Comment: @ombk yes. it allows you to obtain the first solution, 7/5